# Show $\frac{n!}{(n + 1)! + n^2}$ is decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to show that $a_n:=\frac{n!}{(n + 1)! + n^2}$ is a decreasing sequence. I tried to show that $a_{n+1}-a_n<0$ and got:

$a_{n+1}-a_n=n!\left(\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!+(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!+n^2}\right)$, but I'm struggling to show that $\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!+(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!+n^2}<0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: looking at $a_{n+1}/a_n$ might be more fruitful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{(n+1)((n+1)!+n^2)}{(n+2)!+(n+1)^2}<1.$$

Indeed, after dividing by $n+1$ we have

$$\dfrac{(n+1)!+n^2}{(n+2)n!+n+1}<1\iff (n+1)!+n^2<(n+2)n!+n+1\iff n^2-n-1<n!$$

So $a_{n+1}<a_n$ which shows that the sequence is decreasing.

Comment: But how do you show that that is less than 1?

Comment: Note: $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{(n+1)((n+1)!+n^2)}{(n+2)!+(n+1)^2}=\frac{(n+1)!+n^2}{n!((n+1)+1)+(n+1)}=\frac{(n+1)!+n^2}{(n+1)!+n!+(n+1)}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let us prove that $(\frac{1}{a_n})_n$ is increasing.

$$b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}=n+1+\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$$

$$b_{n+1}-b_n=1+\frac{n+1}{n!}-\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$$

$$=1+\frac{ n+1-n^2 }{ n!  }>0$$
 for large enough $n$.

cause the last term goes to zero by ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Show that the reciprocal is $\approx n+1$ and hence increasing.